# take lead values after filtering data

Tags: sql, oracle, case, lag, lead

Below are results from a WITH statement I created:

```
id    prodid    start     end       lead   lag    rnk_prod_first    rnk_prod_last
 1     4654    2/26/19   4/5/19     y      null      1                  7
 1     4655    5/20/19   8/1/19     y      y         2                  6
 1     4656    11/6/19   11/13/19   n      y         3                  5
 1     4657    11/14/19  10/30/20   n      n         4                  4
 1     4658    10/31/20  11/15/20   n      n         5                  3
 1     4659    11/16/20  11/30/20   y      n         6                  2
 1     4660    12/10/20  12/20/20   null   y         7                  1
```

I need to create a logic column that identifies an end date when the `lead` = 'y' or take the next value end date where `lead` = 'y'

lead/lag = Identifies if there are gaps in the start/end dates

expected results:

```
id    prodid    start     end       lead   lag    rnk_prod_first    rnk_prod_last   lead_end_dt
 1     4654    2/26/19   4/5/19     y      null      1                  7             4/5/19
 1     4655    5/20/19   8/1/19     y      y         2                  6             8/1/19
 1     4656    11/6/19   11/13/19   n      y         3                  5             11/30/20
 1     4657    11/14/19  10/30/20   n      n         4                  4             11/30/20
 1     4658    10/31/20  11/15/20   n      n         5                  3             11/30/20
 1     4659    11/20/20  11/30/20   y      y         6                  2             11/30/20
 1     4660    12/10/20  12/20/20   null   y         7                  1             12/20/20
```

So, something like below

```
select case
       when lead <> 'n' then end
       --when lead <> 'y' then --take next value where lead = 'y'
                               --can we use lead and ignore the 'n'?
                               --can we use first_value somehow?
       end lead_end_dt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a cumulative conditional maximum -- in reverse order:

```
select max(case when lead = 'y' then end end) over (partition by id order by order by prod_id desc)
```

If this is the only value you want, there are probably simpler ways to get it.  If so, ask a *new* question, describe your source data, provide the results you want, and an explanation of the logic.